# Fragment not showing when add() method is called

Tags: android, transactions, fragment

here is the declarations:

```
FragmentManager fr = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fr.beginTransaction();
Fragment myFragment = new defaultFragment();
ft.add(R.id.fragment, myFragment);
ft.commit();
```

and here is the `onClick()` method:

```
public void startFragment(View v){
    newFragment = new nextFragment();
    execute();
}
```

execute method :

```
public void execute() {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

i cant the problem but when i click the button that triggers the `startFragment(View v)` method, nothing happens, the fragment is not replaced by the fragment that i want to add on the stack. I think the problem has something to do with this line `transaction.add(R.id.fragment, newFragment);` help please thanks :)

Comment: use `replace`. Also do you see any exceptions in log

Comment: on the logcat, it seems that it called the nextFragment()'s class, but the current fragment did not disappear nor the next frgment didnt appear, i did not use replace because i dont want to lose the datas i have from my previous fragment, so when i pressed the back button i dont have to reload the onCreateView().

Comment: hey @Raghunandan i got it, thank you for helping though :)) thanks to Rajesh Batth

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try adding the fragment to `FrameLayout` instead. I was not able to add it to `LinearLayout`, but I changed it to `FrameLayout` and it worked.

Comment: Ow, LOL! Thanks a lot! how stupid..of course the LinearLayout will add the view next or below the previous fragment. The FrameLayout will put it on TOP of the previous. So it was there, but not visible, as the first fragment fills up the screen (with MATCH_PARENT)

Comment: Just kill me with issue LOL

Comment: But lets say  implement 100 transactions ,would the stack will have all the fragments ? doesnt this will be an issue for memory @Rajesh Batth